# tomcat not starting up in eclipse, Logger ClassnotFoundException, invalid LOC header

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

Tomcat not starting up in eclipse, tomcat is up and running out of eclipse.

Tomcat 7.0.72, eclipse mars2, java 7 all are 64bit

2 different exceptions in logs

1. ZipException for org.apche.commons.digester.Rule
2. ClassNotFoundException for class org.apche.log4j.Logger

> SEVERE: Resource read error: Could not load
>   org/apache/commons/digester/Rule.class. java.util.zip.ZipException:
>   invalid LOC header (bad signature)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)     at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:679)   at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:415)
>     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3512)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1458)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1686)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2272)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1981)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1942)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1332)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> Nov 01, 2016 10:33:42 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase findResourceInternal
>   SEVERE: Resource read error: Could not load
>   org/apache/commons/digester/AbstractObjectCreationFactory.class.
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)     at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:679)   at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:415)
>     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3512)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1458)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1686)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2272)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1981)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1942)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1332)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

**2.**

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LLogger;   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:417)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:891)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Logger  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of fight able to resolve the 2 issues 
  1. by upgrading the commons-digester from 1.6 to 2.1 
  2. by downgrading the version of log4j from 1.2.17 to 1.2.8

don't why eclipse with maven build tomcat 7.0.72 unable to recognize the logger version of 1.2.17 to org.apache.log4j.Logger class